# Issue in giving plurals in Bixby dialogs

Tags: bixby

I had a question regarding plurals in dialog.

Let's say I have a structure

```
structure (MyStructure) {
 property (MyConcept) {
   type {EnumConcept} max (Many)
 }
}
```

And a Value dialog for it:

```
dialog (Value) {
 match: MyConcept(this)
  if (this == 'ABC') {
   switch(plural(this)) {
    case (One) { template("single1") }
    default { template ("plural1") }
   }
  }
  if (this == 'DEF') {
   switch(plural(this)) {
    case (One) { template("single2") }
    default { template ("plural2") }
   }
  }
}
```

By using
Code:

```
#{value(myStructure.myConcept.plural('Many'))}
```

I am able to get "plural1" or "plural2" when myStructure has below values and size of myConcept is 1:

```
myStructure = [
 { myConcept: ABC },
 { myConcept: ABC },
 { myConcept: ABC },
 { myConcept: ABC }
]
```

When size of myConcept is 2 and myStructure has below values,

```
myStructure = [
 { myConcept: ABC },
 { myConcept: ABC },
 { myConcept: DEF },
 { myConcept: DEF }
]
```

using the Code:

```
#{value(myStructure.myConcept.plural('Many'))}
```

is giving NLG as

```
"single1 and single2"
```

What I want in the NLG:

```
"plural1 and plural2"
```

Can someone please help us in giving proper plural NLG for each element of the unique "myConcept" present in the list of "myStructure"?
What I want is to apply plurality to each individual value of an array.
`size(myStructure.myConcept)` = 2.

I want to apply plural to both the values of myConcept.

I do not think in dialogs we have an `for-each` kind of thing available.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell what's going on in the code above. If this answer isn't helpful, consider sharing the full source code somewhere for live debugging.

You can try something like

`#{value(myStructure.myConcept.plural(plural(myStructure.myConcept))}`

The docs has an example like: 
`#{concept(restaurantStyle.plural(plural(restaurant)))}`

Source: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/ref-topics/el-ref#node-evaluation-functions in the `plural(node)` section.

Comment: I have tried this. That also didn't help.
I cannot share the code.
I will try to append a sample code for structures.
Also, What I want is to apply plurality to each individual value of an array.

Comment: I see, the thing is having two of something doesn't make it plural. Each one of your concepts is still singular. `MyConcept` will be plural, since you have many EnumConcepts, but the individual EnumConcepts inside are not, even if they happen to be the same thing. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, and what I wanted was to forcefully apply plurality on each unique EnumConcepts. It looks like platform does not support this as the moment.

Comment: Unfortunately so.